# call function with parameters on any event using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi just wanted to know if this is a correct way. I know we can pass data using object notation and use it. But just wanted to know if the below code is correct. I am not sure about the below syntax.

```
 function isValid(errMessage,errId,errClass){
    alert();
    if($("#"+errId).val()==""){
        $("."+errClass).show();
        $("."+errClass).html(errMessage);
        return false;
    }else{
        $("."+errClass).hide();
    }
}

$("#fname").on("blur",isValid("please enter first name","fname","ferror"));
```

I have seen syntax like below:

```
function test(){
    alert("Hello World");
} 
$("#fname").on("blur",test);
```

check this link for output
http://jsfiddle.net/susheel61/M2jsX/

so just want to make clear if passing parameters directly works or not.

Comment: Your jsfiddle uses a function call not a reference to a function. http://jsfiddle.net/M2jsX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [arguments](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the event handler as a parameter to your event listener:

```
$("#fname").on("blur", {
        msg: "please enter first name", 
        name: "fname", 
        error: "ferror"
    }, isValid);
```

Then your isValid function can handle the data from the event object:

```
function isValid (event) {
    var errMessage = event.data.msg,
        errId = event.data.name,
        errClass = event.data.error;
    if ($("#"+errId).val()=="") {
        $("."+errClass).show();
        $("."+errClass).html(errMessage);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("."+errClass).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: $("#fname").on("blur",isValid("please enter first name","fname","ferror"));
Other options I knew. Just wanted to know if this syntax is legid. thanks

Comment: @susheel it is not. your function call yeilds a result - isValid() and the result is undefined. In this way you provide as a parameter an undefined event handler.

Comment: function test(){
    alert("Hello World");
} 
$("#fname").on("blur",test);

this syntax works So just thought even parameter thing should work. But I was wrong. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code call `isValid` method and assign result as `blur` handler so it's not exaclty right. You should do something like this

```
$("#fname").on("blur",function(){
    isValid("please enter first name","fname","ferror")
});
```

It seems there are other improvements you could do. The most obvious for me is pass `this.id` instead of harcoding the id

```
$("#fname").on("blur",function(){
    isValid("please enter first name", this.id, "ferror")
});
```

Comment: yeah I know this one. But I have seen syntax like:

    function test(){
        alert("Hello World");
    }
    $("#fname").on("blur",test);

so just want to make clear if passing parameters directly works or not

Comment: @susheel: I'm afraid I'm not sure what's your question. Your code as it is doesn't work. You have 2 working alternatives here.

Comment: I think my syntax is not valid. Just wanted to know if that exists. thanks.

Comment: @susheel: notice that instead of attaching method to blur is executing it. So in short, it's not working as you would expect.

Comment: yep. So I think I should pass as object or else follow your way :)